# Проблемы с ajax в codeigniter3

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

JQ:

```
function Success(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.add').click(function () {
            var name = $('[name = name]').val();
            var category = $('[name = category]').val();
            var type = $('[name = type]').val();
            var description = $('[name = description]').val();
            if (name === '') {
                alert("Please, enter name");
            } else if (description === "") {
                alert("Please, enter description");
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "/test2/index.php/ajax/productAdd/",
                    dataType: "text",
                    data: ({"name": name,
                        "category": category,
                        "type": type,
                        "description": description}),
                    success: Success()

                });
            }
        });

    });
```

AJAX controller:

```
   <?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Ajax extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function productAdd() {

        $data['name'] = $this->input->post('name');
        $data['category'] = $this->input->post('category');
        $data['type'] = $this->input->post('type');
        $data['descriprion'] = $this->input->post('description');
        $this->load->model('product_add_model',$data);

     echo $data['name'];


}
}
```

PHP возвращает undefine, и в $_POST ничего не записывается.
Что не так? Заранее благодарен

Comment: Возможно проблема в маршрутизации, исправил маршрутизацию согласно документации, но не помогло. вот, что добавил:$route['main']['post'] = 'ajax/productadd';

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена.

1. Неправильный адрес у ajax запроса. Всем начинающим изучать Codeigniter настоятельно рекомендую юзать base_url().
2. После переноса функции JQ Success в тело ajax запроса:

   ```
               $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/ajax/productAdd') ?>",
               dataType: "text",
               data: ({"name": name,
                   "category": category,
                   "type": type,
                   "description": description}),
               success: Success(data){
                       alert(data);}
           }
   ```

   PHP перестал возвращает undefine, ответ приходит корректный. Буду благодарен, если кто-то пояснит почему.

Comment: потому что вот это `success: Success()` вызывает функцию `Success` без параметров прямо сразу. Вам нужно `success: Success` или `success: function(data) { ... }`. В `data: ...` нет нужды в круглых скобках - хотя это и не ошибка.